# Airflow UI cannot manually trigger a dag

Tags: python, airflow

Versions:

- Airflow v1.10.1
- SQL Server backend
- Web server and scheduler running in same host
- LocalExecutor

A simple hello world DAG won't run when manually triggered using the UI (button). Same example runs fine when run via command line. Would like to allow users to use the UI to trigger a job. Is this a bug.

Example Hello world DAG tested:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_welcome():
    return 'Welcome!'

dag = DAG('say_welcome', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='say_welcome_dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='say_welcome_task', python_callable=print_welcome, dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> hello_operator
```

Test output from command line.

```
(airfow_v1_venv) sshuser@ed41-kp06sp:~/airflowv1/dags$ airflow trigger_dag say_welcome
[2018-12-03 19:38:34,679] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2018-12-03 19:38:34,956] {models.py:271} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/sshuser/airflowv1/dags
[2018-12-03 19:38:35,071] {cli.py:241} INFO - Created <DagRun say_welcome @ 2018-12-03 19:38:34+00:00: manual__2018-12-03T19:38:34+00:00, externally triggered: True>
```

Logs when triggered using UI

```
    context)
  File "/home/sshuser/airfow_v1_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 467, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', u"[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__task_ins__9BEABD04E2A8D429'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.task_instance'. The duplicate key value is (say_welcome_task, say_welcome, Dec  3 2018  7:40PM). (2627) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO task_instance (task_id, dag_id, execution_date, start_date, end_date, duration, state, try_number, max_tries, hostname, unixname, job_id, pool, queue, priority_weight, operator, queued_dttm, pid, executor_config) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (('say_welcome_task', 'say_welcome', datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 3, 19, 40, 9, 787000, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, u'', 'sshuser', None, None, 'default', 1, None, None, None, bytearray(b'\x80\x02}q\x00.')), ('say_welcome_dummy_task', 'say_welcome', datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 3, 19, 40, 9, 787000, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), None, None, None, None, 0, 3, u'', 'sshuser', None, None, 'default', 2, None, None, None, bytearray(b'\x80\x02}q\x00.')))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you tried to override the old `say_welcome` DAG.

Create one called `say_welcome_v1` and give it a shot.

When a new DAG is created, you have to change it's name so that it can be distinguished in the meta DB. Hence the convention of using `_v1`, `_v2`, etc at the end of the DAG name each time there are changes in the DAG.

Since the error you are getting is an integrity error, which occurs when you're trying to insert something into the DB with the same primary key as something else that is already there. Most likely an error from a new DAG with the same name as an old one.

If you don't have any old DAG runs whose history/logs are worth keeping, you can just use `airflow resetdb` followed by `airflow initdb` to reset your database and start from scratch.

You can also delete the old DAG ID form the meta DB using `airflow delete_dag my_dag_id` as of Airflow version 1.10 and above.

Comment: Already did the resetdb option to clear up the database. This doesn't happen when its run via command line. Also from detailed log, I see airflow is trying to insert the record twice into the DB. Not sure why it does that.

Comment: Did you try changing the DAG name to `say_welcome_v1` ?

Comment: yes, have renamed dags. Same error. Even when a new dag is created, has same issue. Works in command line, Triggering using UI has same error.

Comment: Were you available to find a solution?

Comment: yes, haven't found solution. Thinking of dumping MS-SQL Server backend for mysql or postgres since mysql seems to work fine.

Comment: Issue exists in MS-SQL Server backend matadata